# ¿Cómo mostrar mas contenido del que hay actualmente en un elemento haciendo clic en un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo en mi sitio unas "cajas" como las que se indican abajo. Tengo un problema con la altura. Se colocan tres cajas horizontalmente, por lo que quedan como si fuesen "columnas". Cuando hay cierta cantidad de texto las columnas se hacen mas altas.

Me gustaría darle una altura limitada a las cajas (ejemplo 50vh) y al final, poner algún botón estilo "ver mas" que al hacer clic haga que se muestre más contenido del que está actualmente en la caja con altura limitada, también quiero que en ese momento la altura de la caja incremente para que todo el contenido esté adentro.

¿Hay una forma de resolver este problema con Bootstrap?

Éste es mi código  (también en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/maniguerra/pen/bGEdoaM)):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4">

      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiente.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4">

      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiente.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4">

      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiente.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no he usado nunca bootstrap y definitivamente debo aprenderlo, es bastante potente, pero mi recomendacion es que si tu estas creando tu html dinamicamente, colocar un texto estilizado al final de cada una de tus columnas y que por default no se muestre, luego que al ser renderizados automaticamente se ejecute una funcion por cada uno que compruebe si el texto es visible o no, en caso de serlo no mostrar el texto, en caso de no serlo mostrar el texto, este texto o boton a su vez se ligaria con un listener que permita modificar mediante JS el alto de esa columna en especifico.

Comment: Si, con jquery y un poco de css puedo hacerlo de esa manera pero la idea es reutilizar todo lo que pueda, ja. Gracias por la sugerencia de todas maneras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando la propiedad `COLLAPSE`, y de acuerdo al ejemplo mostrado en
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ :

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#segundo1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="segundo1">
    Segundo Año
    </button>
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4 collapse" id="segundo1">
      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiante.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#segundo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="segundo2">
    Segundo Año
    </button>
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4 collapse" id="segundo2">

      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiante.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#segundo3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="segundo3">
    Segundo Año
    </button>
    <div class="text-center border rounded p-4 mt-4 collapse" id="segundo3">

      <div class="mt-4">
        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas
          que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social. </p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiante.</p>
        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Evaluación y retroalimentación.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Erik, sería ideal que explicaras cómo se haría lo que indicas aplicado al código compartido en la pregunta. Creo que no es exactamente lo que quiere el usuario (que tiene 3 columnas)

Comment: Ese sería el camino "rápido" que pide. Tener los contenidos ocultos y mostrarlos al presionar un botón. 
A eso, puede complementar una vista previa justo debajo del botón, y ocultarla al "descolapsar" el contenido.